# Why does my calculator say that the cube root of $0$ is "Infinite"?

Tags: roots, exponentiation, calculator

In all my years, I have known that $0^x = 0\space\space\forall\space\space x \in \mathbb{R}^+ - \{0\}$.

Today, I tried calculating $\sqrt[3]{0}$ on my phone calculator, but I get an unexpected result for this.

[image: The calculator displays "Infinite?" instead of 0]

What could be the reason for this?

If I had to guess it could be some obscure floating point error, but I am not too sure.

Comment: Maybe the calculator does $a^b=e^{b\ln a}$ and obviously $\ln 0$ cannot be calculated. I would also be wary of saying $0^x=0$ for $x\ne 0$: what is $0^{-1}$?

Comment: @StinkingBishop I see, that seems very plausible. Thank you :)

I also did mention that it is only true for $x \in \mathbb{R}^+ - \{0}\$, which is just the positive real numbers.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread that.